# Integrating Google External Login with ABP Framework 6 and React Native: JWT Creation Issue

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, abp

I am currently developing an application using ABP Framework 6 on the backend and React Native on the frontend. My goal is to implement Google external login functionality within my app. To achieve this, I have created an endpoint on the backend that will accept the access token sent by the React Native app. The purpose of this endpoint is to validate the access token and retrieve the necessary user information to create an account within my application.

However, I have encountered an issue related to the creation of JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). I have not been able to find any built-in solutions within the ABP Framework that handle JWT creation for the authentication process. This has left me uncertain about the correct approach to take.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or advice on how to proceed with creating JWTs in my ABP Framework 6 backend for the purpose of Google external login integration. Specifically, I need assistance in determining whether I should develop my own JWT creation mechanism or if there is an alternative solution available within the ABP Framework.

```cs
public async Task<string> CreateGoogleExternalUserAsync([Required] string accessToken)
{
    try
    {
        var validationSettings = new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings
        {
            Audience = new List<string> { _configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"] }
        };

        var payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(accessToken, validationSettings);

        var email = payload.Email;
        var firstName = payload.GivenName;
        var lastName = payload.FamilyName;

        // Create an account in your app using the retrieved information

        // Generate JWT token
        
        // Return the generated JWT token
    }
    catch (InvalidJwtException)
    {
        // Handle invalid access token
        throw new AbpAuthorizationException();
    }
}
```